# VBScipt Array Comparison

Tags: arrays, vbscript

i have a problem with VBScript.

I am trying to loop through an array to compare all the values match.

I.e i have a tring array like the one below.  i want to compare each of the values match using vbscript.

```
tmp(0) = "12345"
tmp(1) = "12345"
tmp(2) = "12345"
tmp(3) = "12345"
tmp(4) = "12345"
```

If i loop over the array i will have to do this twice in order to compare the vals.  But how can i handle the first values.  If the first value is wrong then its never picked up as both arrays are identical.  I do not know how to get around this problem.  Could someone please advise.

```
for x=0 to UBound(tmp)
  for each val in tmp
  if ( tmp(x) <> val)
    print (mismatch)
  End if
  Next
Next
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if I understand your question correctly. Do you want to check if all values of an array are equal? If so, something like this should do:

```
elementsEqual = True

For i = 1 To UBound(tmp)
  If tmp(i) <> tmp(0) Then
    elementsEqual = False
    Exit For
  End If
Next
```

You don't need to compare each element with each other element to check if all are equal. If not all elements are equal, then one of them will be inequal to the first element, so you just need a single loop.